What type of regression do researchers use when creating discharge curves?

Source: https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN024
What type of regression do researchers use to create discharge curves? Is it cubic, or quintic, or something else?

Could you please disclose your definition of "regression"?

Regression in this context is what engineers usually call "interpolation".   Not obvious to me that any such process was used, those curve are ideally just measurements, possibly averaged across a bunch of devices.

if you want to fit those curves something based around atanh might be a good start.

It depends on what they want to do with the answers, but for the figure you showed, I suggest "none".  They probably just collected data often enough that a line through the data points is fine (well, I suppose linear regression between consecutive point is the same as connecting the dots).

There probably isn't a particular linear polynomial model that could reasonably fit one of these discharge curves well, but it depends on what residual would be acceptable for your application.
So your options are a 2D look up table, nonlinear model (if an equation exists) or this paper (or papers, there is a lot to digest here, but someone has tried to solve it):

Numerous studies on the degradation and performance of lithium-ion
batteries have been carried out from both academia and industry [1],
[2], [3]. In particular, Yu applied multiscale logic regression and
Gaussian process regression (GPR) to predict the state of health (SOH)
of lithium-ion batteries [4].

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2352152X2201060X
